# "error: ... An account required by the instruction is missing" when issuing create_metadata_accounts_v3 via CPI

Tags: metaplex, pda, metadata, cpi

I have a token mint address that is a PDA.

Because of that, I cannot just add metadata the usual way. No wallet can sign for the PDA, so my Program needs to add the metadata.

So I created a new instruction "tokMetadata" to my program.

The new instruction is working nicely. I am calling `create_metadata_accounts_v3` from within my instruction, and that works without errors - neither compile time nor runtime errors. As long as the actual `invoke_signed` (to execute the inner instruction via CPI) is commented out...

BUT as soon as I give the `invoke_signed` a try, I am getting a runtime error:

[image: Runtime Error]

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: An account required by the instruction is missing
```

PLEASE NOTE: The error message must be for the INNER instruction (called via CPI `invoke_signed`), not the outer one. The outer instruction is being called without issues when the `invoke_signed` is commented out.

However, I have supplied all accounts that are needed as per documentation (and as per source code of `create_metadata_accounts_v3`!)

Here's my code fragments:

```
pub fn tok_meta(ctx: Context<TokMeta>, okubump: u8) -> Result<()> {
    let a = Pubkey::from_str(ADMINACC);
    let admin = match a {
        Ok(key) => key,
        Err(_e) => return err!(ErrorCode::AdminOnly),
    };
    require!(ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().key == &admin, ErrorCode::AdminOnly);
    let ix = create_metadata_accounts_v3(
        mpl_token_metadata::id(), // program_id,
        *ctx.accounts.metadata_pda.to_account_info().key, // metadata_account,
        *ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().key, //mint,
        *ctx.accounts.mintauth.to_account_info().key, //mint_authority,
        *ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().key, //payer,
        *ctx.accounts.updauth.to_account_info().key, //update_authority,
        String::from("OKU - Bitoku Storage"), // name,
        String::from("OKU"), // symbol,
        String::from("https://okupub.gitlab.io/imgs/Oku.json"), // uri,
        None, // creators,
        0u16, //seller_fee_basis_points,
        false, // update_authority_is_signer,
        true, // is_mutable,
        None, // collection,
        None, // uses,
        None, // collection_details
    );
    invoke_signed(
        &ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.metadata_pda.to_account_info().clone(), // Metadata account
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(), // Mint
            ctx.accounts.mintauth.to_account_info().clone(), // Mint Authority
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().clone(), // Payer
            ctx.accounts.updauth.to_account_info().clone(), // Update Authority
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info().clone(), // System Program
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info().clone() // Rent Sysvar
        ],
        &[&[&OKUSEED, &[okubump]]],
    )?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(okubump: u8)]
pub struct TokMeta<'info> {
    #[account(seeds = [OKUSEED.as_ref()], bump = okubump, mint::decimals = 6, mint::authority = mint)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because it will be checked in the inner instruction
    pub mintauth: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because it will be checked in the inner instruction
    pub updauth: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because it's being checked by the inner instruction
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata_pda: AccountInfo <'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

`tests/tokmeta.js`:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const anchor = require("@project-serum/anchor");
const { SystemProgram, PublicKey, SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY } = anchor.web3;
const { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, getAssociatedTokenAddress } = require("@solana/spl-token");
const { findMetadataPda } = require("@metaplex-foundation/js");
var g = require("./globals");

describe("nodeshop", () => {
  /* create and set a Provider */
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  usr = provider.wallet.publicKey;
  let isLocal = provider.connection.rpcEndpoint.includes("localhost");
  console.log("isLocal:", isLocal);
  const program = anchor.workspace.Nodestore;

  it("Sets the token metadata", async () => {
    const [okuPDA, okubump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(g.OKUSEED)], program.programId);
    console.log("TokMeta: okuPDA is [", okuPDA.toString(), "], bump ", okubump);
    const metadataPDA = await findMetadataPda(okuPDA);
    console.log("TokMeta: metadataPDA is [", metadataPDA.toString(), "], bump ", okubump);

    await program.methods
      .tokMeta(okubump)
      .accounts({
        mint: okuPDA,
        mintauth: okuPDA,
        payer: usr,
        updauth: g.ADMINACC,
        metadataPda: metadataPDA,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      })
      .rpc();

      console.log("TokMeta done.");
    assert.ok(true);
  });

 });
```

Comment: Maybe this is important: I'm passing the exact same account as both `mint` and as well as `mint_authority`. My `mint` is `Ayx6751KcLP74dTdasP7B7wYxPgCQyMX4Lahdv4sMwNs`, which is a PDA generated from my programId together with some seed.

The `mint_authority` shows as the exact same account on the explorer. So I passed in that account both as `mint` and also as `mint_authority`.

Comment: please post the error as text in the description.  search engines won't index screenshots

Comment: Done. Also working on stripping down my (closed source) repo to the bare essentials of adding metadata to a program-owned mint, so that people can try debug. Could act as a template in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after some experimenting. I need to pass another account in the context, namely the `metadata_program_id`.

So the new code for `invoke_signed` is:

```
        invoke_signed(
            &ix,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.metadata_program.to_account_info().clone(), // N E W : Metadata program id
                ctx.accounts.metadata_pda.to_account_info().clone(), // Metadata account
                ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(), // Mint
                ctx.accounts.mintauth.to_account_info().clone(), // Mint Authority
                ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().clone(), // Payer
                ctx.accounts.updauth.to_account_info().clone(), // Update Authority
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info().clone(), // System Program
                ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info().clone(), // Rent Sysvar
            ],
            &[
                &[OKUSEED.as_ref(), &[okubump]],
            ],
        )?;
```

Comment: can you elaborate the answer?  where exactly did the missing account need added?

Comment: Done. Edited the answer.